# How can I find an OPamp, or any other component, that has the required properties when using simulation software like multisim

Tags: design, simulation, multisim

Hi I am require an OPamp that has a slew rate of 1Meg a open loop gain of 100k and a GBW of 1 Meg for a circuit simulation on multisim. I was wondering if there was a way to search for a component by its properties so I can find an OPamp that fits my needs, I am quite new to circuit design and googling hasn't turned up much. Thanks!

Comment: Slew rate is not measured in "Meg".  The unit is typically volts/microsecond, but in any case it's volts per time unit.  Likewise GBW is typically in MHz.

Comment: One way might be to use a parametric search tool to find an actual op-amp with the specs you need (Like on Digikey.com) and see if the manufacturer has a model you can download.

Comment: @JohnD yeah my bad It was written down a 1 Meg which I assume now is Mega rater than a unit

Answer (score 1):

You can check distributors for typical manufacturers, Digikey is one that has a quite good search engine. Once you've identified manufacturers, it's a good idea to go to their website and use their parametric search engine for the parameters that are important to you. TI (which has absorbed Burr-Brown), Analog Devices (which has absorbed Linear Technology) and other players such as Microchip, OnSemi etc. can be considered. Use the datasheets from the vendors for technical data (distributor parametric search engines often have issues or wrong classifications such as mixing typical Vos and maximum when you are sorting), and certain manufacturers appear to be gaming the system by stating specifications in a non-standard way.

The distributor sites are good for identifying manufacturers that may not have occurred to you, looking at breadth of line and stock situation, price, availability of various options, etc., but always the final word is the manufacturer's datasheet.

Once you complete you design and wish to verify it with simulation you can import the SPICE model (typically from the manufacturer's website) and attempt to verify the design. Note that SPICE models usually represent 'typical' behavior and your design should be based on worst-case specifications so that every time the circuit is reproduced, with whatever batch of components, it will perform within all requirements over the required range of temperatures and other environmental conditions.